# error in login with facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to implement a login with facebook in my application. I have already imported the sdk and set all the right settings on my developer account on facebook. But now when I try to login with facebook it redirects me right back to the loginactivity instead of the mainactivity.

The facebook button is imported in my xml file like this:

```
    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

This is what my launch activitys oncreate function looks like:

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);
                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You cancelled while logging in, please login to gain access.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error appeared, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

When I click the facebook login button I get redirected to the facebook app and when I successfully log in the facebook app asks for permission, but than I just get redirected to the login activity.

Comment: try removing `finish();`

Comment: Try a toast message in onSuccess(). Do you have fb app installed in device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found what the problem was.
I forgot a line of code that actually initiates any action after you're logged in, which is:

LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));

You should enter this after you've set the behaviour of your LoginManager.